# Create diff/patch for specific git commits

Tags: ruby, git, diff, patch, rubymine

Suppose, I have similar git history:

```
sha_001 'Some commit description'
sha_002 'Some other commit description (without regularity)'
sha_003 'Some other commit description (without regularity)'
sha_004 'Some other commit description (without regularity)'
sha_005 'Some other commit description (without regularity)'
sha_006 'Some other commit description (without regularity)'
```

How to create patch for specified commits?

I know about:

```
git diff sha_003..sha_001
```

but this is for commits range. I need something, like:

```
git diff sha_002,sha_005,sha_006
```

### Question specification

In RubyMine I can do this:

[image]

But

- In RubyMine I can't specify commits (only by selecting them by mouse)
- I'd like to do this without RubyMine, with plain cli git tool and Atom as patch viewer.

Also, I wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'tempfile'

abort "Usage:\ndiffco hash1,hash2,hash3" if ARGV.empty?

commits = ARGV.first.split ','

patch = ''
commits.each do |commit|
  commit_data = <<-SEPARATOR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------ PATCH FOR COMMIT: #{commit} -----------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SEPARATOR
  commit_data += `git show #{commit} --stat`
  commit_data += `git show #{commit} --unified=20`
  patch += commit_data
end

path = File.join Dir::Tmpname.tmpdir, Dir::Tmpname.make_tmpname('commits', '.diff')

File.open(path, 'w') { |f| f.write patch }
`atom -a #{path}`
```

It allows me to see single diff/patch file in Atom editor, but I'd like to not see middle changes stuff.

Comment: In RubyMine (or in any other JetBrain IDE) there is cool feature for multi select commits from git history (in VersionControl window).
It does exactly what need by clicking and selecting commits by mouse with holding Command key. 
Unfortunately I did not found way to specify filter by more then one commit, 
and if there are a lot of commits in history and in list, it is very long time to select them all (and it is hard to not to miss anyone).

Comment: You want a single patch file for several non-sequential commits?

Comment: Yes, I need single patch (don't need middle changes)

Comment: For what it's worth, `git diff` *doesn't* do commit ranges. Normally `X..Y` means "commits reachable from `Y` excluding commits reachable from `X`" but in `git diff` it means "diff specific commit `X` vs specific commit `Y`".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, this is possible directly with just git-diff. But you could do an interactive rebase to squash the specified commits together `git rebase -i sha_006^`. Then you can use git-diff on the new commit created by rebase. If you don't want to lose you initial commits, just run rebase in a new temporary branch.

Comment: Also like with `git cherry-pick sha_002`, git-rebase making conflicts. Is there any faster / simpler way?

Comment: If there are merge conflicts between your selected commits, this is an inherent problem of your commit history. If  sha_002 cannot be applied without sha_003 there is no way to create a single patch including sha_002 but not sha_003 without resolving this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

`git format-patch -o patches sha_006..sha_001` will create patch files for each commit from sha_006 to sha_001 and save all those patch files to patches folder.